# Auto expanding textarea in Django

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I want to have a textarea which will auto expand(**vertically**) with input text in Django crispy form. Is there any simple way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="text"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
```